# K means feature learning

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose you have a data set composed of n images as training examples. You run clustering on each image ( initializing 3 clusters per image) and learn the centers. Is it ok to then take the cluster centers themselves as features for a supervised learning algorithm and thus have a vocabulary for each image that way or is it inconsistent ? Are there are other more consistent measures that can be used ?

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question".  I assume an "image" is a pixelmap, but in this context, what's a "feature"?  What's a "center"?  What's a "vocabulary"?  What is "inconsistent"?  Why three clusters, and not 2 or 17?  **What problem are you actually trying to solve?**

Comment: @JɛﬀE I think valentin are talking about the Bag of Words algorithm.

Comment: Yes indeed I was having the Bag-of-Words Algorithm on my mind. "Mea culpa" for not being explicit enough.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd say you can. "Coordinates of point of importance inside image" qualifies as a feature so you can use it in supervised learning.
If clustering is a way to discover that coordinate you can use that.

A practical example: say you want to use "x-coordinate of left eye" as a feature in a classification problem. It does not matter how you get the object's values for that feature, as long as the values are accurate. If you have an algorithm (e.g. a clustering algorithm) which can compute the values you can use it.